# Responsive site 100% width does not work on Safari

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm not an expert in css and I am building my first ever responsive WP Theme. It seems I got it working on chrome and FF (at least it looks ok on my mac), but in Safari it seems that width 100% does not work when resizing browser window (the same on iPhone and android phone). The site is http://www.designstest.co.uk/ stylesheet: http://www.designstest.co.uk/style.css

Thank you for reading. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, as I checked your code, I found a lot of issues.
I strongly advise you to hire a designer to build your website with a responsive layout.

If you don't want to hire a designer, there are a lot of free responsive layout frameworks available for you to use.

also, you have a visible horizontal scrollbar in your website, if you wish to remove it simply add this to your CSS.

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

This is what I see when using FireFox on Windows 8
[image: Windows8FFDisplay]

Comment: Thank you. I think you're right I need to hire a professional it's too big project for beginner.